# JSFF Syntax Coloring

Tags: eclipse, jsf, eclipse-mars

I recently downloaded Eclipse Mars.2. The project I'm working on involves jsf files (I'm specifically focusing on files with the .jsff extension, as normal jsf files seem fine). While they seem to run correctly, they have no syntax color and act/look-like normal text from a .txt file when viewed. All of my other file types have the normal coloring scheme that comes with Eclipse. I have tried to change the syntax coloring through the Windows > Preferences option, but I didn't find anything involving jsf/jsff files. I don't have much experience working with these kinds of files, but I was told it should be possible to get color syntax into my jsff files. Am I looking in the wrong place, am I misunderstanding something, or is this a configuration issue?

Comment: Windows -> preferences -> general -> file associations. on the right side look for the extension *.jsf, click on it, see what is associated to it on below window, then create a new one *.jsff and add the same thing you have on the *.jsf it should work.

Comment: Eclipse Mars is 13 releases and more than 5 years behind. Instead of wasting time with outdated software, get Eclipse 2020-12.

Comment: You should check if there's an existing, correct, Content Type to add the filename extension to first (one named for JSF fragments), before manually tweaking any File Associations.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It looks like this did the trick! After doing what you said, and trying to run the file as a JSP and receiving a warning, the only additional step was to add the *.jffs file type to JSP under the Content Types section in Preferences and restarting Eclipse. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. I will add it as an answer then so you can mark it as accepted if it helped you out.

Comment: @nitind Your answer may be more accurate, as I did have to go through Content Type to get the .jsff extension working even after adding it manually.

Comment: @JorgeCampos So I got rid of the *.jsff file extension I made in the File Associations section, and it seems like the Eclipse color syntax works without it, making me think that just doing what nitind said, going to Content Type and adding it there, is what actually fixed the issue, and the File Associations action was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to `Windows -> preferences -> general -> file associations`. on the right side look for the extension *.jsf, click on it, see what is associated to it on below window, then create a new one *.jsff and add the same thing you have on the *.jsf it should work.

As you added on the comments you had to do the same process for the JSP under content types. Adding it here so it may help others.